# How to simply stream video from a remote server?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I have a remote debian server used as storage server. I would like to stream some videos directly from the server without downloading the file in advance.

So far I create a http server in the same folder with the file I need using this command

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

and using `vlc` I can play the movie from my machine.

This works but I will say that is a "basic" solution.

Can you suggest a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What about this solution is not meeting your requirements?

Comment: the first reason that is really slow...is almost impossible to watch a movie in this way. It works well for short low-quality movie.The second reason is that using this approach I'm not able to load subtitles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a media server rather than a standard webserver. Personally, I've played with the following:

- Vlc has a webinterface (if you enable it). By default it listens only on localhost, but changing that requires editing a single file. There's also an android app that allows you to control it. You can have it stream, it will stream subtitles, etc. Downside: pretty manual process, no 10ft interface. Upside: very flexible, best solution if you *only* want to use vlc clientside.
- a headless dlna system like rygel. If you install rygel and rygel-playbin, you'll be able to play your media files from any dlna-enabled device. This includes many smartphones and tablets, game consoles, and some smart tv's. Downside: no support to play on the machine itself, pretty basic. Upside: fully headless, can be configured over ssh, no gui required serverside.
- a dedicated 10ft ui like kodi (previously known as xbmc). Kodi has an official android remote app, allows you to control playback of your media files as with a regular remote, and has some support for dlna streaming too, both as client and as server. Upside: very slick interface, works really well if you hook it up to your tv, very easy to use compared to the other two. Downside: can't run headless, and the streaming options aren't as flexible as vlc.